# Google ical url fails but import works

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I am using the Google web based calendar and have gone to `Other Calendars > From URL` and my dates are imported but the times come through as 12.00-12.30. However if I export the calendar as a ics file and import it using `Other Calendars > Import` the entries and times pull through correctly.

What is wrong with this? What do I need to change so the ical read link works as I don't want users to have to import the file (its more dynamic!).

Comment: Timezone issue? Do you have a sample or steps to reproduce this? What platform is the other Calendar on? I did a random test and the times also work from URL. We need more info to figure out what's the issue in your scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a case of "its working now" scenario - I suspect it is the headers from the server and a possible caching thing. If it happens again - I will update this ticket and give more info.